# Embedding/map that respects boundaries?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

What do you call an embedding (or map in general) from a manifold to a manifold $i: M \rightarrow N$, such that $i(\partial M) \subseteq \partial N$?

Is there a difference, if we define it as a relative map $i: (M,\partial M) \rightarrow (N,\partial N)?$

Comment: Embeddings such that $\iota^{-1}(\partial N)=\partial M$ sometimes are called "proper embeddings." This terminology is a bit unfortunate since it clashes with the open of a "proper map" in general topology.

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase from Hirsch's book "Differential Topology" which applies to a very closely related situation.

Namely, if the inclusion $i(\partial M) \subset \partial N$ is strengthened to an equation $i(\partial M) = i(M) \cap \partial M$, and if for each $x \in \partial M$ the subspaces $D_xi(T_x(\partial M))$ and $T_{i(x)} (\partial N)$ are required to be transverse subspaces of the vector space $T_{i(x)} N$, then one says that $\text{image}(i)$ is a **neat submanifold** of $N$. I suppose one can also say in this situation that $i$ is a **neat embedding** of $M$ in $N$.

This is definitely a stronger property than what you stated, but one might argue that it more accurately reflects the intuition of "respecting boundaries".

Comment: Thanks! How would I best describe the situation that I embed an open space into an open space, such that "it respects boundary". In particular, if I want to embed an open interval in an open disk, such that the closure would be a neat embedding. I'm not sure if I'm describing things right.

Comment: I don't know of any special terminology for that situation.